# Spring Boot how to use HiddenHttpMethodFilter

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

As we all know, forms only support `GET` or `POST` methods, like this:

```
<form method="[GET|POST]" action="/user/create">
```

If our controller has a `PUT` mapping, we get a 405 error, which means we can only use `GET` or `POST` but not `PUT`.

```
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/create", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    public ModelAndView createUser(@ModelAttribute("user") Users user, BindingResult bindingResult){
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("list");
        // do something...
        return mv;
    }
}
```

In spring MVC, we can solve this problem:

First, create a hidden field like this:

```
<form method="[GET|POST]" action="/user/create">
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="put"/>
```

Second, add a filter

```
<filter>  
    <filter-name>HiddenHttpMethodFilter</filter-name>  
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter</filter-class>  
</filter>  

<filter-mapping>  
    <filter-name>HiddenHttpMethodFilter</filter-name>  
    <servlet-name>springmvc</servlet-name>  
</filter-mapping>
```

In this way, we can use the `PUT` method.

But how can I do it in Spring Boot? I know Spring Boot have a class named `WebMvcAutoConfiguration` which owns a method `hiddenHttpMethodFilter`, but how can I use the class?

Comment: You shouldn't need to do anything as Spring Boot will automatically configure the hidden http method filter for you

Comment: @AndyWilkinson thanks a lot man.  I edit my question, But if I do not configure the hidden http method filter, how can I use a put submit in html form.

Comment: Like you normally would. Just put the element in the form...

Comment: Since Spring Boot 2.2, the filter is no longer automatically configured. Set `spring.mvc.hiddenmethod.filter.enabled=true` in your `application.properties` to enable it again.

Comment: Note that using `HiddenHttpMethodFilter` opens your application to a whole bunch of new CSRF attacks. Be sure you have other means of blocking requests from external forms. And no, CORS does not work for forms.

Answer (score 17):

Add the following to your `application.properties` file:

```
spring.mvc.hiddenmethod.filter.enabled=true
```

This will automatically configure the `HiddenHttpMethodFilter` class.

Next, use `th:method="DELETE"` on the form to have `Thymeleaf` add the hidden field automatically.

**Note**

- For Spring Boot < 2.2 always registers the filter
- For Spring Boot 2.2 or higher you need to set the property

Comment: [Updated]@Deblauwe. I use Sping boot 2.7.0. I put in the form th:method="delete", and atDeleteMapping, and the : "spring.mvc.hiddenmethod.filter.enabled=true" in application.yaml, and it does not work. It says about "Request method post not supported". Any idea please? It is not supported in newest Spring boot versions. Thanks in advance

Comment: @Thomas_Mylonas please ask a separate question for this.

Comment: Hello @Deblauwe sir. Thanks for the reply. I used the atBean FilterRegistrationBean, I saw in the next reply. For me, my spring boot did not to create it for me, using the yaml property you mentioned. But, I will make this comment a separate question as you told me, so, you can help me, and the thymeleaf community. I will do it in the next 2 hours (I am in work right now)

Comment: @Deblauwe - Hello sir. I made this question as you adviced me: "stackoverflow.com/questions/72744349/…". Your experience in this topic will be valuable to me. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6):

I had dealt with this problem not long ago. You only need to and a Bean under anyone `@Configuration` class. Such as:
[image: add HiddenHttpMethodFilter]

Then, you could use delete request on form. Such as:
[image: use delete request on form]

Comment: If you use Spring Boot, add `spring.mvc.hiddenmethod.filter.enabled=true` to your `application.properties` to avoid the manual bean configuration. If you use Thymeleaf for the templates, you can use `th:method="DELETE"` to have Thymelaf add the hidden field automatically.

Comment: @WimDeblauwe your comment deserves more upvotes, worked for me!

Comment: Turned it into a separate answer now for easier upvoting :)

Answer (score 0):

Addition to Wim Deblauwe answer.
If you use **application.yml**, you need to add:
**spring:mvc:hiddenmethod:filter:enabled: true**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).