# Delete requestmapping is throwing me this error 405 Http method Get is not supported by this URL

Tags: java, spring, http-delete, http-status-code-405

Below is my method to delete and return a string, simple and straightforward

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/deletetest", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
    @ResponseBody
    public String DeleteUser() {
        return "something";
    }
```

But I go Get method not supported, which is weird since i state that my *method = RequestMethod.DELETE*
[image]

Any insight?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/65461244/2039546

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you set an endpoint to `RequestMethod.DELETE` the endpoint will only accept a HTTP DELETE request. Your browser issues a GET request.

Comment: You could use Postman or a similar tool to issue a DELETE request.