# How to get a delete method of CRUD to work on a Spring project

Tags: java, spring, h2, crud

Having some difficulties in dealing with CRUD delete method on a Spring based project. Keep getting an 404 error. Due to the fact of me being a newbie to programming I'm not able to figure out the problem on my own. I tried to seek some solutions on various YouTube guides and articles, tried to re-write, but nothing helped. Huge thanks in advance to anyone who could help me out. Attached some portion of code that is dealing with DELETE method of CRUD:

Service:

```
public void deleteVisit(Long id) {
    repository.delete(id);
}
```

Controller:

```
@DeleteMapping("delete-appointment/{id}")
public void deleteAppointment(@PathVariable Long id) {
    dentistVisitRepository.delete(id);
}
```

Thymeleaf:

```
<td><a th:href="@{delete-appointment/{id}(id=${appointment.id})}">Delete</a></td>
```

Comment: Isn't that a GET in your html?

Comment: I haven't used Thymeleaf, but generally an 'href' is not going to invoke a `delete` call. So is there some Javascript that does the translation to the `Delete`? [This question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24256051/delete-or-put-methods-in-thymeleaf) seems to also suggest something more is needed.

Comment: Thanks. SavedBeau offered the similar way of solving this, but keep getting an 404.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In the controller you need to call the service

```
@DeleteMapping("delete-appointment/{id}")
public String deleteAppointment(@PathVariable Long id) {

    //You might have to first find it before deletion to ensure there are no errors
    appointmentService.deleteVisit(id);
    return "Deleted";
}
```

2. In the Service you call deleteById from repository

```
public void deleteVisit(Long id) {
    repository.deleteById(id);
}
```

3. The default HTTP method used by anchor tag is GET you need to create a form to be able to change the http method

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{delete-appointment/{id}'(id=${appointment.id})}" th:method="delete" >
  <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="delete" />
  <button type="submit" id="submitButton"> </button>
</form>
```

If you are using spring boot 2.2+, add following into you `application.properties`

```
spring.mvc.hiddenmethod.filter.enabled=true
```

After spring boot 2.2+, this hidden method filter is disabled by default. For more details [check here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62063236/2143128).

Comment: Tried to rewrite your solution, but keep getting an 404 error, unfortunately. Will it be any use of posting my entire project?

Comment: Forgot to say, that my CRUD repository doesn't have a deleteById method, so I'm using delete instead.

Comment: @natt i have updated the answer, hope you are using spring boot 2.2+

Answer (score -1):

this code take **object** parameter `repository.delete(Entity)`

but this code take Long Parameter used this code to delete by id

```
  public void deleteVisit(Long id) {
    repository.deleteById(id);
}
```

if you want delete by **entity** you can use this code

```
  public void deleteVisit(Long id) {
   Entity entity=repository.findById(id).get();
    repository.delete(entity);
}
```

Comment: While possibly accurate, how does this address the 404 error? Because I would think the original code wouldn't compile or it would just fail to delete the object.

Comment: i am written this code if your id actually exist in you data base but you can check it when check if present  like this `if(repository.findById(id).present())` @KevinO